# onclick is set for <tr> How to disable for one <td>

Tags: javascript, onclick

Suppose onclick handler is set for a `<tr>` is it possible to disable/overwrite it for one particular `<td>`?

`<tr onclick='somefunction()'>
  <td> </td> <!--onclick should work here-->
  ...
  <td> </td> <!--onclick should not work here-->
  ...
  <td> </td> <!--onclick should work here-->
</tr>`

Of course I can set it for each `<td>` separately or pass the name of a `td` to the function and decide what to do based on this name, but it seems like there should be a simpler solution.

Comment: You could add a class to that td, and check for in your function, and not do anything if it has it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `somefunction` you could check the `cellIndex` of the `td`, and return early, if a non-clickable cell has been clicked. Something like this:

```
function somefunction (e) {
    if (e.target.cellIndex === 1) {return;}
    /* Do something, the td is clickable */
}
```

To get this work with an inline handler, you've to pass the event object:

```
<tr onclick='somefunction(event)'>
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u268eqns/).

Things will get a bit more complex, if you've elements within cells. In that case you have to find a `td` parent element, like so:

```
function somefunction (e) {
    var target = e.target; // Cache the target element
    while (target) { // Iterate through elements
        if (target.tagName === 'TD') { // TD found, stop iteration
            break;
        }
        target = target.parentElement; // Set target as a parent element of the current element
    }
    if (target === null) {return;} // Check that we really have a TD
    if (target.cellIndex === 1) {return;} // A non-clickable cell clicked
                    :
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u268eqns/2/).

**Edit 2018**
In 2018 elements have `closest()` method, hence the loop above is not needed, `target = e.target.closest('td')` will make sure a `td` is used.

A very simple way would be to use CSS `pointer-events: none`, but unfortunately this doesn't work <strike>in FF in this particular case</strike> in IE<11 at all, though works well in Chrome and IE11. Also preventing pointer events would be bad, if the cell happens to contain interactive elements.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u268eqns/3/).

Comment: this works great. Is it possible to look at some property of `td` like class or name instead of index? Replacing cellIndex with class didn't work. Sorry for stupid questions: I don't have any real experience with javascript or other web techs.

Answer (score 10):

I found the easiest was to stop the event being passed to the parent html using onclick=event.stopPropagation() in the `<td>` tag.

So `<td class=whatever onclick=event.stopPropagation()>cell data<td>`

Comment: this one solved the problem for me thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:-

Try something like this.

HTML:

```
<tr id="row">
    <td> </td> <!--onclick should work here-->
    ...
    <td class="noChange"> </td> <!--onclick should not work here-->
    ...
    <td> </td> <!--onclick should work here-->
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var row = document.getElementById("row");

    for (i=0; i<row.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (row.childNodes[i].class != "noChange") {
            row.childNodes[i].onclick="doStuff()";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this works, but doesn't actually answer the question : (. What if there's more than one row in the table?

Comment: Then loop through the table and do this for every row.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr onclick='somefunction(this)'> 
    <td><input type="text"></td> <!--onclick should work here--> ... 
    <td><input type="text"></td> <!--onclick should not work here--> ... 
    <td><input type="text"></td> <!--onclick should work here-->
</tr>
</table>
<script>
function somefunction(element) {
  var td = element.children;
  console.log(td);
  var inputObj = td[1].children;
  console.log(inputObj[0]);
  inputObj[0].disabled = true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The children property 'element.children' returns a list of an element's child elements, as an HTMLCollection object.
enjoy :)